# Using sed to add a number while keeping all other variables the same

Tags: awk, sed

I have been trying to add a number in front of my two digit numbers in my file to make all of my CHRM have three numbers following it:

```
Original Data
scaffold1.1|size30980855
scaffold10.1|size30980855


Output Data
scaffold001.1|size30980855
scaffold010.1|size30980855
```

As you can see I am trying to make my numeric value consist of a three digit code. I was thinking of using sed but I do not know how to keep the digits on the other side... Here is an example of what I mean

```
sed 's/scaffold[0-9]*/scaffold00[0-9]*/g'
```

what do I put in the second bracket to keep the number that was originally there.

any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `perl` is okay

```
$ perl -pe 's/scaffold\K\d+/sprintf "%03d", $&/e' ip.txt 
scaffold001.1|size30980855
scaffold010.1|size30980855
```

- `scaffold\K\d+` match digits preceded by `scaffold`
- `/e` so that we can use Perl code in replacement section
- `sprintf "%03d", $&` print the matched digits as 3 character wide integer and zero filled

With `sed` use Capture Groups:

```
$ sed -E 's/(scaffold)([0-9]\.)/\10\2/; s/(scaffold)([0-9]{2}\.)/\10\2/' ip.txt 
scaffold001.1|size30980855
scaffold010.1|size30980855
```

For given problem, only two cases need to be changed

- `scaffold` followed by single digit and `.` needs two zeros added
- `scaffold` followed by two digits and `.` needs single zero added
- `s/(scaffold)([0-9]\.)/\10\2/` will add a single zero for first case to in turn become second case
- `s/(scaffold)([0-9]{2}\.)/\10\2/` will add another zero

Comment: This would work if scaffold is deep within my file data,correct? Perl is awesome my friend.

Comment: yeah, it would work any where in the line... but only first occurrence, use `g` if there are more